# Only 30 candidate are eligible then why 31?

Tags: support, moderator-election

In [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) it says:

> Please note that due to the large number of nominees, only the top 30 nominees by reputation are currently eligible and displayed. see all 31 nominees.

Only 30 nominees are eligible but I can see **see all 31 nominees**. Why is it doing that?

What is meaning of this text?

> moderator candidates
>
> 30/31

Comment: @downvoter Why down vote?

Comment: It's not clear what's confusing you - there are thirty eligible nominees, which are shown, but if you want to see **all** nominees (including one currently-ineligible nominee) you can.

Comment: Please understand that down-votes on meta don't affect your reputation and don't imply that yours is a bad question but rather that someone disagrees with your point, that's all. So to answer your question, "why down vote?", it's because someone disagrees with you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There were 30 candidates, then another user with higher rep nominated themselves to be a candidate. After that, the candidate with the lowest reputation is hidden by default, but there are still 31 candidates (as someone may withdraw before the end). The candidates are only filtered out (by top 30 users with most reputation) at the end of the nomination phase.

Comment: Because if someone withdraws before the primary phase, that person at position #31 can go through anyway.